# Do you have the solution for this React-Three-Fiber Slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-three-fiber

First time I ask a question but then I am stagnating ...

I'm trying to make a slider with React-Three-Fiber and I can't seem to make the slider draggable.

Here is my code:

```
  let canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas")
  let pressed = false;
  let startx;
  let x;

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    pressed = true;
    startx = e.offsetX;
    canvas.style.cursor = "grabbing";
  });

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    canvas.style.cursor = "grab";
  })

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    canvas.style.cursor = "grab";
    pressed = false;
  })

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    if(!pressed) return;
    e.preventDefault();

    x = -e.offsetX / 200;
    position = x / 10;
  })
```

Do you have a solution to make this work?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

i would wrap the canvas into a div and use regular react events. you can also use regular dom overflow:scroll divs in front of the canvas, they support grabbing by default on mobile.

some examples

- basic scroll https://codesandbox.io/s/tying-canvas-to-scroll-offset-itfgk
- more involved https://codesandbox.io/s/camera-scroll-tu24h
- grabbing implemented in webgl https://codesandbox.io/s/minimap-qf8d0

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will watch this!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, how would you do it as simply as possible?